# How to get value stored in array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m storing values as object which i get dynamically, now i need to retrieve those values, its simple question but i didnt get the answer so i asked here.

for example:

```
/* Adding values dynamically into array of saveData. */
at first :
id = 1
gettext = 'Y'
text = 'Hello world'
at second :
id = 2
gettext = 'N'
text = 'JavaScript'
etc....
```

My code:

```
var saveData = {};
var objterm = {};

objterm["valueID"] = id;
objterm["valueGot"] = gettext;
objterm["text"] = text;
saveData[id] = objterm; // Saving values in array...
```

How can i retrive a value eg: say, saveData[1] -> gettext, text

```
// I tried the below to get value as
        var obj = _.find(saveData, function(obj) { return obj.id == id }); // did nt get values
```

Comment: Using lodash / underscore is a good idea.  Which library are you using? I may be able to provide an answer that uses the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provided both `saveData` and `objterm` are simple objects, so if you wanted to retrieve specific data from some specific entry to `saveData` all you need to do is this:

`saveData[id].valueGot`

based on

```
objterm["valueID"] = id;
objterm["valueGot"] = gettext;
objterm["text"] = text;
```

Comment: You could also use `saveData[id]['valueGot'];`

Comment: Yeah, you could, personal preference really. I prefer to use dot notation for objects when possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is working after adding http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js
For _.find & _.findWhere method.

```
var saveData = {};
var objterm = {};

objterm["valueID"] = 1;
objterm["valueGot"] = 'Y';
objterm["text"] = 'javascript';
saveData[1] = objterm;

 var obj = _.find(saveData, function(obj) { return obj.valueID == 1 });
  var obj2 = _.findWhere(saveData, {valueGot: 'Y' });
 console.log(obj)
 console.log(obj2)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anil826/7ay25qwu/